# ASP.NET C# use of ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript pass parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code which should call a function called ShowPopup in my client side script but for reason, when I call this function nothing happens.

```
  string pg = "Test";
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup(pg);", true);
```

If I do the following:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                   this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('Test');", true);
```

it works fine. It does show up in the popup. Any idea what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: show your popup js function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is **ShowPopup** is expecting a string value.

### Correct Code

```
string pg = "Test";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup",
   string.Format("ShowPopup('{0}');", pg), true);
```

About C# code will generate the following **valid** javascript -

```
<script>
   ShowPopup('Test');
</script>
```

### Error Code

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", 
   "ShowPopup(pg);", true);
```

Notice that above code C# will generate the following **invalid** Javascript -

```
<script>
   ShowPopup(pg); // Invalid Javascript code
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you Used Update Panels Then You can Use:

```
string pg = "Test";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('"+pg+"');", true);
```

Other Wise You can Use

```
string pg = "Test";
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
                (GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('"+pg+"');",true);
```

in your case

```
string pg = "Test";
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
            (GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ShowPopup('"+pg+"');",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use  String interpolation:**

```
string pg = "Test";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", $"ShowPopup('{pg}');", true);
```